# Bourgain's paper on kakeya conjecture

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, book-recommendation, harmonic-analysis, additive-combinatorics

What is the necessary background in additive number theory/arithmetic combinatorics  required for someone  to be able to read and understand Bourgain's paper:
ON THE DIMENSION OF KAKEYA SETS AND
RELATED MAXIMAL INEQUALITIES  on the arithmetic method and the Kakeya conjecture?

Can you recommend some sources/books to learn the basics in these two disciplines?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @hardmath I edited and included the title of the paper